# Why do local changes seem to exist equally in both branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have different branches in my git repo.  I checkout a new branch and apply a change.  When I checkout back to my master branch, it still shows the change.  Similarly, when I stage changes for commit in the new branch, then checkout the master branch, it again shows those changes as staged.

Why do changes in my branch `regrid-more-flexible-times` seem to be shown (either staged or unstaged) even when I switch back to my branch `master`?  See below for an illustration.

```
$ git branch
* master
  regrid-more-flexible-times
  regrid-sst
$ git checkout regrid-more-flexible-times
Switched to branch 'regrid-more-flexible-times'
$ git status
# On branch regrid-more-flexible-times
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ vim regridworkflow.py
$ git status
# On branch regrid-more-flexible-times
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   regridworkflow.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So far so good.  I've made changes in my branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`.  Now I need to head back to `master` to access the codebase without any changes.

```
$ git checkout master
M       mms/src/main/python/regridworkflow.py
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   regridworkflow.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Huh?  Why does branch `master` show the unstaged changes I made while on branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`?  Perhaps it is only aware of differences after I stage them?

```
$ git checkout regrid-more-flexible-times
M       mms/src/main/python/regridworkflow.py
Switched to branch 'regrid-more-flexible-times'
$ git add regridworkflow.py
$ git status
# On branch regrid-more-flexible-times
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   regridworkflow.py
#
$ git checkout master
M       mms/src/main/python/regridworkflow.py
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   regridworkflow.py
#
```

...and why does branch `master` show the changes I staged while on branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`?

My aim is to be able to work an changes while on branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`, but to be able to checkout the `master` branch which does not have those changes.  Why does the workflow above not do so, and how should I do instead to achieve this?

Comment: You could have more than one working copy (two independent clones of the repository). Or use "shelves" (don't know exactly what that is). Otherwise your uncommitted changes will "move with you" as you switch branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've made changes in my branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`.

No, you've made changes to your wokring copy.

> why does branch `master` show the changes I staged while on branch `regrid-more-flexible-times`?

There's only one staging area per working copy. They don't exist for each branch. See `git stash` on how to save changes without committing them.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> **git checkout <branch>**
>
> To prepare for working on , switch to it
> by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by
> pointing HEAD at the branch. ***Local modifications to the files in the
> working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the <branch>.***

This is why your unstaged changes remain when you checkout master.

---

You would either want to commit your changes to the branch then checkout master, or use `git stash` to save off the changes without committing them.